# На страницу wordpress не вставить ничего перед шорт-кодом

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, шорткод

Добрый день!
У меня на сайте wordpress стоит плагин, который с помощью

```
 add_shortcode('choosecard', 'clashroyale');
```

создаёт шорт-код `[choosecard]`, который стоит на странице.
Этот плагин с помощью `echo`выводит на страницу нужные данные (html).
Если я в админке wordpress добавляю текст или другой шорт-код перед `[choosecard]`, то он почему-то выводится после него на странице.
Не могу понять почему.
Код всего плагина выложить не могу, иначе могут быть неприятности на работе :(
Версия wordpress: 4.5.2
Заранее очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Измените в функции, которая возвращает html для вашего шорткода echo на return.